# How to do LOD in DirectX 9?

Tags: c++, optimization, directx

I know in DirectX 11 you can use the awesome tessellation feature for LODs, but knowing that DirectX 9 doesn't have this feature, how would I go about creating LODs for the models in my 3D application/game to speed it up?

I heard back in the old days before DirectX 10 or 11 came out, people used to create many of the same type of models but just with different polycounts (i.e: one with very low polycount for far away objects and one with a high polycount for very near objects).

But doing this would mean doubling or even tripling the size of models in the game right? Is there any other approaches in achieving LODs in DirectX 9? Or is this really the best soultion when it comes to DirectX 9? Can someone at least point me in the right direction for this issue I can atleast go away and do more research about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating multiple LOD meshes using mesh simplification algorithms (or by hand) might not be as bad as you think in terms of memory consumption. As in mipmaps, since your simplified mesh have much less vertices, they shouldn't triple the size of your in-game models. And you don't have to keep the high-resolution meshes in video memory if you're not going to be using them for a while.

An alternative to save memory is to simplify meshes by discarding vertices only. This way, you can use a single vertex buffer and have different index buffers for each LOD. You might get slightly lower quality LOD meshes, but the memory overhead of keeping them all in memory will be much smaller.

If I'm not mistaking, tessellation is for subdivision, so it wouldn't help you anyways if you want a coarser mesh (though it can probably help interpolate between LODs.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and info. So just to confirm, in a way you're saying swapping these high to low poly meshes or low to high poly meshes isn't that bad of an idea?

Comment: Yes. If you try to approximately halve the number of vertices at each LOD, then you'll always stay within a factor of two of the mesh memory usage.